Convert wall lamp from receptacle power to 120V AC cord/plug
I have a wall lamp which is supposed to be connected directly to the mains power in the wall. I don’t have access to those lines and don’t want to play with them anyway. Is it possible to connect a standard 120V cord and plug to the wires in the lamp so I can just plug it into a regular outlet like a table lamp would?

Does this lamp have its own switch or does it depend on a wall switch?

Could you please post a picture of this lamp? Model number, too, if it's there. I'm curious about a lamp that doesn't have a plug on its power cable...

@Triplefault   OP said it is a wall lamp.  Wall lamps might be 50/50 if they come with cords.  Most people don't like cords hanging down their walls.

Ah, good point, @crip659 ! This could then depend on if it's a lamp "fixture" that needs a junction box to hang on, or an actual fully-backed lamp for non-permanent hanging on a nail/screw in the wall.

It’s a Phillips Hue lamp, so controlled by app, no switch needed, and comes with a mounting bracket.

Could one convert it to use a cord and plug? Certainly! However, one must be knowledgeable as to what is safe and meets local code. Some things to consider:

A grounded, three-wire cord should be used, with the ground connected to the metal of the fixture.
Likely a hole will be needed for the wire to go though the front of the fixture, That new hole also needs a strain-relief and/or grommet.
Some means to attach or hang the fixture will need to be improvised.
Does a switch need to be added, either on the fixture or for the outlet?

When all that is done, will the lamp be satisfactory? There will be a wire from the lamp, down to the power outlet, running along the wall.

In other words it is possible, but you can buy a plug-in wall lamp starting at about $15 and as you can see here, the conversion is not trivial.

@jay613, yes, but it very well may be worthwhile in an individual case -- but not to be done without forethought.

It’s a Phillips Hue lamp which comes with a mounting bracket, and requires no switch as it is controlled by app via a Wi-Fi bridge. A plug-in wall lamp will not serve the same.
